# Save last value of Angular 2 *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

In the following code I would like to save the last user & Index so that I may paginate every 50 users forward or back.

```
<tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="var user of users; let index=index; let isLast=last">
                  <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
                  <td><span *ngFor="var ext of user.extensions; let isLast=last">{{ext}}{{isLast ? '' : ', '}}</span></td>
                  <td>{{user.loginName}}</td>
                  <td>*Blank*</td>
                  <td>{{user.userType}}</td>
                  <td>*Blank*</td>
                  <td>*Blank*</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <ul class="vgVspNextLastList">
        <li><small class="vgVspNextLastTag" (click)="showNext();"> Next > ></small></li>
        <li><small class="vgVspNextLastTag" (click)="showLast();">< < Last </small></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the last value already in `users`. If you use

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
```

then the last user is

```
this.users[this.users.length - 1]
```

Comment: At which point can I pass this value back to the component without further user interaction?

Comment: Just after `this.users` gets the data assigned.